# Doesn't Google Webmaster Tools v2.0 API work anymore?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

I'm trying to edit Google Webmasters site settings (set targeting country), but as far as I know [v3](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/sites) doesn't allow to do this, so I'm using [v2](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol).

However, I get `401 Unauthorized` response for all the Webmaster Tools v2 endpoints. Here are steps I have performed:

- Visit [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)
- Picked Webmaster tools v2
  [image]
- Authorized this API and exchanged authorization code for tokens. (After that I got a message "The access token will expire in 3599 seconds.")
- Then hit "List possible operations" and chosen "List sites"
  [image]
- Finally, clicked "Send the request" and got 401
  [image]

I did it several times I all the time I got the same result.

What is the reason of such behavior? Is Google Webmaster Tools v2 deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its deprecated.  I cant find an official deprecation but all the documentation on V2 just links to v3.  Which is probably why I cant find the official deprecation date.  Google normally gives you a year to move once they deprecate something.

I found a [comment](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/CLJC_2fVsy0) from Google dated 11/20/15 stating

> Version 2 is on it's way to be completely deprecated, so I would move
>   away from it. Whatever still works and breaks, likely will not be
>   fixed.

Time to move to v3

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was afraid of. By chance, do you know how to [set target country](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en) with the new API? That would solve my problem completely.

Comment: Nope I don't see any update or patch methods for the new api.  Weird.

Comment: Note: I sent some feed back need to get it removed form playground it shouldn't be there v3 should be.